# Canvas not showing scrollbars although the content does not fit the page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am showing a canvas in the page, the resolution of what's appearing in the canvas is high that it doesn't all fit ont he page but the scrollbars are not appearing making it impossible to scroll up/down (no problem with width for now). I tried changing Display to "block" but that did not help.

Comment: I don't think that the canvas has that sort of functionality, I believe you would have to set the width and height so that the content fit the canvas. Since canvas is a drawing. You would probably have to implement your own scrolling on the canvas.

Comment: @Rchristiani is right. I've tried to implement scrolling in canvas and it is somewhat of a pain. you have to track your viewport and adjust whas showing through the X and Y positions of the viewport

Comment: Is it possible to set the scrolling on the div holding the canvas so we are basically scrolling the canvas or does the comment above apply to that too?

Comment: @user220755 If you had the canvas at the full size and then set the div `overflow: scroll;` You should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add a jqueryUI scrollbar and scroll through your tall canvas.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/a9KDB/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
body{ background-color: ivory; }
div, canvas {
    position:absolute;
}
.wrapper {
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin:30px 0 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:green;
}
.vertical-scroll {
    left:320px;
    top:10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 20px;
    height: 300px;
}
.vertical-scroll div.bar {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
}
#mycanvas {
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var wrapper;
        var canvasHeight;
        var vScrollHeight;
        var canvasWrapperHeight=300;

        $(".bar").draggable({
            containment: "parent"
        });

        $(".bar").on("drag", function (event, ui) {
            var ctop=(-ui.position.top * canvasHeight / canvasWrapperHeight);
            canvas.style.top = ctop + "px"
        });

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
          canvas.width=this.width;
          canvas.height=this.height;
          canvasHeight=this.height;
          vbarHeight=canvasWrapperHeight*canvasWrapperHeight/canvasHeight;
          document.getElementById("vbar").style.height=vbarHeight+"px";
          ctx.drawImage(this,260,0,300,this.height,0,0,300,this.height);
        }
        img.src="http://sciencedude.blog.ocregister.com/files/2008/02/zot1-copy.jpg";

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrap1">
        <canvas id="mycanvas" width="300px" height="300px" />
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-scroll" id="vscroll">
        <div class="bar" id="vbar"></div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```