# Move a tkinter canvas with Mouse

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to move a whole tkinter `Canvas` with Mouse Click (hold) + Motion of the mouse.  I tried with `canvas.move` but it doesn't work unfortunately.

**How can I scroll in the whole canvas ?** (not move each element of the canvas, but rather scroll the displayed area of the canvas)

```
import Tkinter as Tk

oldx = 0
oldy = 0

def oldxyset(event):
    global oldx, oldy
    oldx = event.x
    oldy = event.y

def callback(event):
    # How to move the whole canvas here?
    print oldx - event.x, oldy - event.y

root = Tk.Tk()

c = Tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg='white')
o = c.create_oval(150, 10, 100, 60, fill='red')
c.pack()

c.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", oldxyset)
c.bind("<B1-Motion>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The canvas has built-in support for scrolling with the mouse, via the `scan_mark` and `scan_dragto` methods. The former remembers where you clicked the mouse, and the latter scrolls the window an appropriate amount of pixels.

Note: the `gain` attribute tells `scan_moveto` how many pixels to move for each pixel the mouse moves. By default it is 10, so if you want 1:1 correlation between the cursor and the canvas you will need to set this value to 1 (as shown in the example).

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400, background="bisque")
        self.xsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.ysb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))

        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        for n in range(50):
            x0 = random.randint(0, 900)
            y0 = random.randint(50, 900)
            x1 = x0 + random.randint(50, 100)
            y1 = y0 + random.randint(50,100)
            color = ("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue")[random.randint(0,4)]
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1, outline="black", fill=color)
        self.canvas.create_text(50,10, anchor="nw", 
                                text="Click and drag to move the canvas")

        # This is what enables scrolling with the mouse:
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.scroll_start)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.scroll_move)

    def scroll_start(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

    def scroll_move(self, event):
        self.canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly what I needed !
Is it possible to have an infinite (or nearly infinite) Canvas, so that I can scroll as far as I want to the right/left/top/bottom ?

Comment: @Basj: I don't think it's infinite, though the actual limit isn't documented. Just experiment by making the scrollregion bigger and bigger. My guess is, the coordinates are 32 bit ints.

Comment: Thanks again for this scrolling code @BryanOakley. For "zooming", would you use something like `canvas.scale` ? I did an implementation by doing it myself from scratch when zooming, but I think there is probably something built-in in `tkinter` ?

Comment: Am I wrong, or this scrolling function won't move `Text` widgets embedded in a `Canvas` @BryanOakley ? I did some tests and it seems that it doesn't move such widgets...

Comment: @Basj: it depends on how you do the embedding. If you use `create_window`, they will scroll along with everything else. They won't scroll if you use pack, place or grid.

Comment: It works with `create_window`, the widgets can now be scrolled and zooming in / works with `canvas.scale`.

Comment: Be aware that [**the scrollregion should be bigger than the canvas**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74682813/13629335)