# Tkinter Canvas : Scale on moving object

Tags: python, events, scroll, zooming, tkinter-canvas

I do not know if my question is a stupid one or a tricky one.

So, using Tkinter and Canvas, I succeed to implement a scrolling/zooming function that work perfectly, thanks to this post [Move and zoom a tkinter canvas with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787523/move-and-zoom-a-tkinter-canvas-with-mouse). I also add a binding to resize the canvas size when the window size change without trouble.

Using `coords` and `after`, I have no trouble to move `object` around.

The trouble came when I tried to combine everything.

- Moving and scrolling : no trouble
- Scrolling and Zooming : ok
- Zooming, moving and scrolling : do not work

The code bellow reproduce the trouble (`python 2.7`, work on windows). For what I can see, the trouble come from the scaling, maybe caused by the change of `coords` of the objects, that induce the canvas resizing, and then disable the scaling? If it is the case, I need help to solve this issue. If it is not the case, I need help to found the issue...

By removing/disable the line `self.master.after(50, self.Display)`, moving do no occur anymore.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import math

class Example:
    def __init__ (self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.interval = 0
        self.SizeX, self.SizeY = master.winfo_width(), master.winfo_height()
        #Canvas Frame
        self.SystemCanvasFrame = tk.Frame(master, bg='black')
        self.SystemCanvasFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #Canvas
        self.SystemCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.SystemCanvasFrame, width=int(self.SizeX*0.75)-20, height=self.SizeY-20, bg="black")
        self.SystemCanvas.focus_set()
        self.xsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.SystemCanvasFrame, orient="horizontal", command=self.SystemCanvas.xview)
        self.ysb = tk.Scrollbar(self.SystemCanvasFrame, orient="vertical", command=self.SystemCanvas.yview)
        self.SystemCanvas.configure(scrollregion=(-500,-500,500,500))
        self.SystemCanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        #add the canvas with scroll bar in grid format
        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.SystemCanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # This is what enables using the mouse to slide the window:
        self.SystemCanvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.move_start)
        self.SystemCanvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_move)
        #windows scroll
        self.SystemCanvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)        
        #resize the main window
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self.UpdateCanvasSize)

        #Create Objects
        self.Size = 5 #object Size
        x0 = 0
        y0 = 0
        x1 = self.Size
        y1 = self.Size
        self.SystemCanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill='green', outline='green', width=3, tags='Green')
        self.SystemCanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill='red', outline='red', width=3, tags='Red')
        self.SystemCanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill='yellow', outline='yellow', width=1, tags='Yellow')

        self.Display()

    def Display(self):
        self.interval += 0.5 #speed parameter
        GreenPos = self.UpdatePosition(0.1*self.interval, (0,0), 50)
        RedPos = self.UpdatePosition(0.02*self.interval+180, (0,0), 200)
        YellowPos = self.UpdatePosition(0.3*self.interval, RedPos, 10)

        self.MoveObject('Green', GreenPos)
        self.MoveObject('Red', RedPos)
        self.MoveObject('Yellow', YellowPos)

        self.master.after(50, self.Display) #Disable to zoom

    def MoveObject (self, Obj, pos): #only move object that are in the field of view
        """Move Obj to the given position (tuple - xy)"""
        ID = self.SystemCanvas.find_withtag(Obj)      
        #Convert the Center of the object to the coo need for tk
        x0 = pos[0] - self.Size/2.0 #radius of the circle
        y0 = pos[1] - self.Size/2.0
        x1 = pos[0] + self.Size/2.0
        y1 = pos[1] + self.Size/2.0
        self.SystemCanvas.coords(ID, x0,y0,x1,y1)

    def UpdatePosition(self, angle, center, distance):
        """Calculate next object position around the Center at the Distance and speed determine by Angle (in Radian) - Center of the object"""
        h = center[0]
        k = center[1]
        radius = distance
        Rad = angle
        x = h+radius*math.cos(Rad)
        y = k+radius*math.sin(Rad)
        return (x, y)

    def UpdateCanvasSize(self, event):
        """Permit to resize the canvas to the window"""
        self.SizeX, self.SizeY = self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height()
        self.SystemCanvas.config(width=int(self.SizeX*0.75)-20, height=self.SizeY-20)

    def move_start(self, event):
        """Detect the beginning of the move"""
        self.SystemCanvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
        self.SystemCanvas.focus_set() #security, set the focus on the Canvas

    def move_move(self, event):
        """Detect the move of the mouse"""
        self.SystemCanvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    def zoomer(self,event):
        """Detect the zoom action by the mouse. Zoom on the mouse focus"""
        true_x = self.SystemCanvas.canvasx(event.x)
        true_y = self.SystemCanvas.canvasy(event.y)
        if (event.delta > 0):
            self.SystemCanvas.scale("all", true_x, true_y, 1.2, 1.2)
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            self.SystemCanvas.scale("all", true_x, true_y, 0.8, 0.8)
        self.SystemCanvas.configure(scrollregion = self.SystemCanvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1125x750')
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to Tkinter so this might not be the most elegant solution but I hope it gives you an idea on how to solve the problem.

The `zoomer` method scales your coordinates but these coordinates are reset anytime you call `MoveObject` or `UpdatePosition`. I added code that keeps track of the scale factor, `self.scale`, and a method `update_coord` that scales a given coordinate based on the scale factor. Finally, I called `update_coord` in the `MoveObject` and `UpdatePosition` methods.

Here is the working code;

```
import Tkinter as tk
import math

class Example:
    def __init__ (self, master):

        self.scale = 1 #Added

        self.master = master
        self.interval = 0
        self.SizeX, self.SizeY = master.winfo_width(), master.winfo_height()
        #Canvas Frame
        self.SystemCanvasFrame = tk.Frame(master, bg='black')
        self.SystemCanvasFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #Canvas
        self.SystemCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.SystemCanvasFrame, width=int(self.SizeX*0.75)-20, height=self.SizeY-20, bg="black")
        self.SystemCanvas.focus_set()
        self.xsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.SystemCanvasFrame, orient="horizontal", command=self.SystemCanvas.xview)
        self.ysb = tk.Scrollbar(self.SystemCanvasFrame, orient="vertical", command=self.SystemCanvas.yview)
        self.SystemCanvas.configure(scrollregion=(-500,-500,500,500))
        self.SystemCanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ysb.set, xscrollcommand=self.xsb.set)
        #add the canvas with scroll bar in grid format
        self.xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.SystemCanvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # This is what enables using the mouse to slide the window:
        self.SystemCanvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.move_start)
        self.SystemCanvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move_move)
        #windows scroll
        self.SystemCanvas.bind("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)        
        #resize the main window
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self.UpdateCanvasSize)

        #Create Objects
        self.Size = 5 #object Size
        x0 = 0
        y0 = 0
        x1 = self.Size
        y1 = self.Size
        self.SystemCanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill='green',   outline='green', width=3, tags='Green')
        self.SystemCanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill='red', outline='red', width=3, tags='Red')
        self.SystemCanvas.create_oval(x0,y0,x1,y1, fill='yellow', outline='yellow', width=1, tags='Yellow')

        self.Display()


    #**Added Method
    def update_coord(self, coord):
        """Calculate the scaled cordinate for a given cordinate based on the zoomer scale factor"""
        new_coord = [coord_i * self.scale for coord_i in coord]
        return new_coord


    def Display(self):
        self.interval += 0.5 #speed parameter
        GreenPos = self.UpdatePosition(0.1*self.interval, (0,0), 50)
        RedPos = self.UpdatePosition(0.02*self.interval+180, (0,0), 200)
        YellowPos = self.UpdatePosition(0.3*self.interval, RedPos, 10)

        self.MoveObject('Green', GreenPos)
        self.MoveObject('Red', RedPos)
        self.MoveObject('Yellow', YellowPos)


        self.master.after(1, self.Display) #Disable to zoom

    def MoveObject (self, Obj, pos): #only move object that are in the field of view
        """Move Obj to the given position (tuple - xy)"""
        ID = self.SystemCanvas.find_withtag(Obj)      
        #Convert the Center of the object to the coo need for tk
        x0 = pos[0] - self.Size/2.0 #radius of the circle
        y0 = pos[1] - self.Size/2.0
        x1 = pos[0] + self.Size/2.0
        y1 = pos[1] + self.Size/2.0
        c_0 = self.update_coord([x0, y0]) #Added
        c_1 = self.update_coord([x1, y1]) #Added
        self.SystemCanvas.coords(ID, c_0[0], c_0[1], c_1[0], c_1[1]) #Added/Edited 

    def UpdatePosition(self, angle, center, distance):
        """Calculate next object position around the Center at the Distance and speed determine by Angle (in Radian) - Center of the object"""
        h = center[0]
        k = center[1]
        radius = distance
        Rad = angle
        x = h+radius*math.cos(Rad)
        y = k+radius*math.sin(Rad)
        return self.update_coord([x, y]) #Added/Edited

    def UpdateCanvasSize(self, event):
        """Permit to resize the canvas to the window"""
        self.SizeX, self.SizeY = self.master.winfo_width(), self.master.winfo_height()
        self.SystemCanvas.config(width=int(self.SizeX*0.75)-20, height=self.SizeY-20)

    def move_start(self, event):
        """Detect the beginning of the move"""
        self.SystemCanvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
        self.SystemCanvas.focus_set() #security, set the focus on the Canvas

    def move_move(self, event):
        """Detect the move of the mouse"""
        self.SystemCanvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    def zoomer(self,event):
        """Detect the zoom action by the mouse. Zoom on the mouse focus"""
        true_x = self.SystemCanvas.canvasx(event.x)
        true_y = self.SystemCanvas.canvasy(event.y)
        if (event.delta > 0):
            self.SystemCanvas.scale("all", true_x, true_y, 1.2, 1.2)
            self.scale *= 1.2 #**Added
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            self.SystemCanvas.scale("all", true_x, true_y, 0.8, 0.8)
            self.scale *= 0.8 #**Added
        #self.SystemCanvas.configure(scrollregion =  self.SystemCanvas.bbox("all")) #**Removed (This disables scrollbar after zoom)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1125x750')
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```