# How to Zoom and Pan Image in Python?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, zooming, tkinter-canvas

I have an image: [image]

I wish to pick a point on this image. However, when I display the image, I can only see a part of it on the screen, as follows: [image: Image visible on screen]

I wish to know how to zoom out and pan the image in a way that I am able to also pick a point on the same image and do the processing.

I tried to use the code given here : [Move and zoom a tkinter canvas with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787523/move-and-zoom-a-tkinter-canvas-with-mouse/48069295#48069295) but the problem is that this displays the image on a different canvas, and all of my further processing is supposed to be on the image itself.

I do not want to use the image resize function because that leads to change in pixel orientation/pixel loss

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert canvas coordinates to image coordinates during processing the image itself.

For example, for to the code "[Move and zoom a tkinter canvas with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069295/7550928)" add the following event to the `__init__` method of the Zoom class:

```
self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-3>', self.get_coords)  # get coords of the image
```

Function `self.get_coords` convert coordinates of right mouse button click event to the image coordinates and print them on console:

```
def get_coords(self, event):
    """ Get coordinates of the mouse click event on the image """
    x1 = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)  # get coordinates of the event on the canvas
    y1 = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    xy = self.canvas.coords(self.imageid)  # get coords of image's upper left corner
    x2 = round((x1 - xy[0]) / self.imscale)  # get real (x,y) on the image without zoom
    y2 = round((y1 - xy[1]) / self.imscale)
    if 0 <= x2 <= self.image.size[0] and 0 <= y2 <= self.image.size[1]:
        print(x2, y2)
    else:
        print('Outside of the image')
```

Also I advise you to use more anvanded zoom technique [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48137257/7550928). Especially the 2nd code example after bold **EDIT** text.