# Limit the .scan_dragto method in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to know if there is a way to set a limit to the `.scan_dragto` method in tkinter.

In my current project, using `.scan_dragto` correctly drags my canvas widget. But I can drag it endlessly. Is there any way to limit this drag?

I've already tried to set a max size to my canvas using `maxsize`, but it didn't work.

This part of my code is something like this one below.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

img = tk.Canvas(root, bg = "white", width = 1100, height = 600)
img.grid()

#Some canvas objects
#...

img.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda event: img.scan_mark(event.x, event.y))
img.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: img.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates what you've tried. Given that you're the one providing arguments to `scan_dragto`, it stands to reason you can limit those arguments. Plus, the `scrollregion` method lets you define the extent to which a canvas can scroll.

Comment: Here's an example of a canvas that can be scrolled, but doesn't allow unlimited scrolling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646727/7432

Comment: Sorry, this was my first questions. Done it

Answer (score 1):

As @Bryan Oakley pointed in his comment, using `scrollregion` solved my problem. The syntax is shown below:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

img = tk.Canvas(root, bg = "white", width = 1100, height = 600)
img.grid()
img.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 800))

#Some canvas objects
#...

img.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda event: img.scan_mark(event.x, event.y))
img.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: img.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1))

root.mainloop()
```

The line `img.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 800))` limits the horizontal scroll from 0 to 1000 (in canvas coordinates) and the vertical scroll from 0 to 800.