# Tkinter Canvas - 2px internal padding appearing

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I noticed a strange behavior with the Tkinter Canvas implementation. Here is a small snippet to highlight this behavior.

```py
shall_configure_innerframe = False
shall_configure_periodically = False


from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from tkinter.ttk import Style, Frame, Label

win = Tk()

# Styles
Style().configure('outer.TFrame', background='black')
Style().configure('inner.TFrame', background='red')

# Outer frame (to highlight Canvas area)
frame = Frame(win, style='outer.TFrame')
frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both', padx=1, pady=1)

# Canvas
canvas = Canvas(frame)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both', padx=3, pady=3)

# Inner frame
innerframe = Frame(canvas, style='inner.TFrame')
win_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=innerframe)

# Let's add some content to actually see the frame
Label(innerframe, text='AAA').pack()

# Callback when canvas is configured (to set window width to the full canvas)
def on_canvas_configure(event):
    canvas_width = event.width
    canvas.itemconfig(win_id, width=canvas_width)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_canvas_configure)

# Callback when innerframe gets configured
def on_innerframe_configure(event):
    region = canvas.bbox('all')
    print(f'onscroll: {region}')
    canvas.config(scrollregion=region)

if shall_configure_innerframe:
    innerframe.bind('<Configure>', on_innerframe_configure)

# Function to periodically call the on_innerframe_configure
def configure_periodically(*args, **kwargs):
    on_innerframe_configure(None)
    win.after(2000, configure_periodically)
    
if shall_configure_periodically:
    win.after(2000, configure_periodically)

win.mainloop()
```

As you can see, the "core" part of a window is a Canvas with a Frame inside, and this frame is then resized to fit the canvas (width).

According to the configuration of the two booleans at the beginning, I can get one of the three results highlighted here:

[image: Three different canvas options]

Basically:

- If I never configure the `scrollregion` parameter (so `shall_configure_innerframe = False` and `shall_configure_periodically = False`) I get result A: the inner frame aligns with the Canvas border
- If I configure the `scrollregion` parameter later in time (so `shall_configure_innerframe = False` and `shall_configure_periodically = True`) I get result A until the timer runs out, then as soon as the function gets called I get result B: the inner frame first aligns with the Canvas border, then a 2px vertical padding appears (but not on the horizontal side)
- If I configure the `scrollregion` parameter as soon as possible (so `shall_configure_innerframe = True` and `shall_configure_periodically` doesn't matter) I get result C: the inner frame has a 2px padding both on vertical and horizontal sides

What I noticed in the latter case is that the inner frame is shifted, not resized, since the last two pixels disappear outside the Canvas (I noticed this in the real application, where content disappears).

In all cases the calculated bbox is always the same: `onscroll: (0, 0, 382, 19)`.

Why is the canvas behaving this way? For the moment I'd simply add a 4px padding on the right, but this does not seem correct to me.

Note: of course the real application is a bit more complicated, and I actually need to set the scrollregion

Comment: `confine=False` solves this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74682813/tkinter-canvas-scrolling-scrollregion-explained-un-restricted-area

Comment: @СергейКох Actually `confine=False` is not the solution; I want the view to be confined. However trying the code you linked I found the solution, and I'm posting it as an answer to help future people searching for this or similar "strange" issues on the Canvas

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling around with my code (and the one Сергей Кох linked in a comment to the question) I found out that actually the default implementation of the Canvas has a 2-pixel highlight border around.

NOTE: with respect to the question's image, I removed the screen scaling, so I could also "measure" the pixels on the UI

This is for instance what happens when I simply set the background yellow (with `canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='yellow')`) without creating the window:

[image: Yellow background]

As you can see, starting from the outside there are

- The 3px black border caused by the outer frame
- 2 grey pixels
- The yellow background area, 164 pixels wide

In the `on_canvas_configure` function the `event.width` parameter is set to 168, which is yellow + grey.

I was not able to find a function to compute the actual view width of the Canvas. So I decided to compute it manually.

For this reason, I changed the on_canvas_configure function with the following one:

```py
def on_canvas_configure(event):
    canvas_width = event.width + 2 * int(self._canvas.cget('highlightthickness'))
    canvas.itemconfig(win_id, width=canvas_width)
```

[image: Fixed]

As you can see, the inner widget is now the correct width of the canvas, and does not go beyond that.

In order to remove the 2px border around, I just need to explicitly remove the highlight:

```py
canvas = Canvas(frame, highlightthickness=0)
```

[image: Fixed without border]

(in both cases I set `shall_configure_innerframe = True`, since that is the real use case I have).

TL;DR: you should always remember that the canvas, if not instructed otherwise, will have a 2px grey border. This border will be considered in the item width/height, so the view area will be reduced by twice the border size amount. To solve this, either set the `highlightthickness` to 0 or take its size into account when setting the content size

**EDIT:**

The previous answer used the `canvas.canvasx(0)` function to calculate the highlight thickness. While this produced good results when the scrollregion was as large as the canvas, it caused issues when it was larger. Thus I preferred to go with a more robust solution (hence the "migration" to `cget`). This way I was able to create two functions to retrieve the actual size of the canvas:

```py
    def canvas_view_width(self) -> float:
        return canvas.winfo_width() - 2 * int(canvas.cget('highlightthickness'))
        
    def canvas_view_height(self) -> float:
        return canvas.winfo_height() - 2 * int(canvas.cget('highlightthickness'))
```